# Should I test my website against all browsers & all versions?

Tags: testing, browser, web, compatibility

Prob 1 : Do I need to care about some bugs of Firefox 2, firefox 3, chrome7,8, opera 8,9... etc that can make my site look weird on these old browser ? I wonder if the developer changed the HTML-render-engine everytime they update their browser & make my site imcompatible with all version.

Will almost visitors keep their browser up2date ? If not, please suggest me with some tools that can help me test my site against FF, Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari in all major versions. 
(I've try this by some online services but it's extremely slow to take screen shot of my site)

Prob 2 : Is there any difference among browser for PC, Tablet, Mobile (except the screen resolution) that can cause a display error for my website ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, whether you should test your website against:

- **all browsers**: Yes, because Windows users have any among IE, Chrome, Firefox & in remote cases, Safari, Opera among others. Whereas Mac users will have Safari, Chrome as their preferred one.
- **all versions**: Probably no. Limit yourself to only those which are still supported, i.e. IE 7 onwards & so on.

---

But, the key lies in the engine upon which the browser is based upon. It can be said:

```
                     *OS: Kernel :: Browser:Engine*
```

For instance, Chrome, Safari, both are based upon "webkit" layout engine.
Check out, web-layout engines: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers

(This consideration will save a lot of effort as you can be rest assured that browsers using same engine will behave in a similar manner.)

*Also, keep in consideration your target audience, this can help you limit your browser choices.*

***And yeah, most browsers have developer tools (F12 key), which allow you to simulate the previous versions of the browser.***

---

But, all in all, the answer is relative & depends solely upon how much time you have & how much effort, time, testing are you willing to spend...

Answer (score 0):

Developers should always try to make their websites cross browser compatible. I personally wouldn't worry about the very old versions of browsers (ie. Firefox 2) and would instead display a message telling the user that they should upgrade their browser.

As a lot of users don't always upgrade their browsers straight away, you should still try to maintain the compatibility of your site with these browsers.

I would recommend this tool for checking the browser compatibility of your website https://browsershots.org/

Answer (score -2):

As a general rule there is a quick and dirty way to test your site. The dirty assumption is that if it works on IE, it will work in anything since IE handles more things differently than other browsers.

With that being said, you can test on IE by opening up an IE9 browser window and hitting F12. This will bring up a box on the bottom that allows you to check the site for compatibility quickly. On the top right hand corner of the box that popped up there are two drop down menus to change the IE engine that is interpreting the site (The one on the left is the Engine and the one right is compatibility mode that the engine is running). You can switch between IE7 engine to IE9 engine seamlessly and without needing a 3rd party application to do so.

Comment: Working on IE does not mean it'll work on anything. It could be an IE bug.

Comment: That's rigth alex. I've faced some weird bugs with Chrome & Opera.